# Why is ElementTree.iterparse() raising a ParseError?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmldata = file('my_xml_file.xml')

tree = ET.parse(xmldata)
root = tree.getroot()
root_iter = root.iter()
```

Now I can call `root_iter.next()` and get my `Element` objects. The problem is the real file I am working with is huge and I can't fit all of it in memory. So I am trying to use:

```
parse_iter = ET.iterparse(xmldata)
```

If I call `parse_iter.next()` it raises the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    parse_iter.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1260, in next
    self._root = self._parser.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1636, in close
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1488, in _raiseerror
    raise err
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code I had was perfectly fine, except I was calling `ElementTree.iterparse()` on a file object I had already read with `ElementTree.parse()`. D'oh!

[image]

So for those who happen to make the same mistake, the solution is to either open a new file object or use [`file.seek(0)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to reset the file cursor.